# Spark Scala copy column from one dataframe to another

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a modified version of the original dataframe on which I did clustering,
Now I want to bring the predicted column back to the original DF (the index is ok, so it matches). How am I supposed to do this?
With this code I get an error.

```
println("Predicted:")
dfWithOutput.show
println("Original:")
originalDF = originalDF.withColumn("cluster", dfWithOutput.col("prediction")

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) prediction#2121 missing from (list of columns in the original df)
```

Comment: Spark doesn't work that way. The only option is join on some form of unique key. But it looks like the XY-problem. Why do you create a separate `DataFrame` at all?

Comment: @user8371915 because I had to convert some label clumn to numerical values , remove some columns to not participate in clustering etc etc

Comment: I doesn't sound right. You either mix old and new APIs, or don't use the new one correctly. Could you share some code that explains the context?

Answer (score 3):

you need to join the two dataframes and then select the columns you're interested in

Comment: yes, that's what I ended up with eventually.. unlike pandas, spark DFs are "sql-based"

Comment: How to do that exactly ?