# Error in copying columns between 2 spark datasets based on a condition

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to copy values of a few columns from one dataset to another based on condition. I use the following method to do so. The method throws an error which I cannot solve. Seeking some help to solve this..

```
public static void copyColumns(String copyFrom, String copyTo, String outputFile, String idCol, String[] copyCols) {
    Dataset<Row> from =  readCSV(copyFrom);
    Dataset<Row> to = readCSV(copyTo);
    Dataset<Row> output = readCSV(copyTo);

    for(String copyCol : copyCols) {
        logger.info("Column Copy Initiated: " + copyCol);
        Column copiedCol = when(from.col(idCol).equalTo(to.col(idCol)), from.col(copyCol)).otherwise(to.col(copyCol));
        output = output.withColumn(copyCol, copiedCol);
        logger.info("Column Copy Success: " + copyCol);
    }

    writeCSV(output, outputFile);
}
```

`readCSV` and `writeCSV` are used to read and write csv files.

Associated error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) Text#9,Text#47,Remarks#6 missing from Category#87,Checked#92,Text#85,Sample Ngrams#83,TextLength#91,words#89,Payload Value#94,PredictedLabel#90,UserName#80,CreatedAt#77,Payload Type#93,ActualLabel#86,Remarks#82,URL_2#79,ID#76,URL_1#78,Sample Tokens#84,Caption#88,UserType#81 in operator !Project [ID#76, CreatedAt#77, URL_1#78, URL_2#79, UserName#80, UserType#81, CASE WHEN (Text#9 = Text#47) THEN Remarks#6 END AS Remarks#114, Sample Ngrams#83, Sample Tokens#84, Text#85, ActualLabel#86, Category#87, Caption#88, words#89, PredictedLabel#90, TextLength#91, Checked#92, Payload Type#93, Payload Value#94]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: Text,Text,Remarks. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;
>   !Project [ID#76, CreatedAt#77, URL_1#78, URL_2#79, UserName#80, UserType#81, CASE WHEN (Text#9 = Text#47) THEN Remarks#6 END AS Remarks#114, Sample Ngrams#83, Sample Tokens#84, Text#85, ActualLabel#86, Category#87, Caption#88, words#89, PredictedLabel#90, TextLength#91, Checked#92, Payload Type#93, Payload Value#94]
>   +- Relation[ID#76,CreatedAt#77,URL_1#78,URL_2#79,UserName#80,UserType#81,Remarks#82,Sample Ngrams#83,Sample Tokens#84,Text#85,ActualLabel#86,Category#87,Caption#88,words#89,PredictedLabel#90,TextLength#91,Checked#92,Payload Type#93,Payload Value#94] csv

Comment: What is the value of 'copiedCol' when the two values are different? Shouldn't you add 'otherwise' or at least an 'if' statement to the 'withColumn'?

Comment: @eliasah Please remove the duplicate marking if the following reason holds good. This question is about conditional copy of columns between datasets. The already asked question is just about complete copy of columns between datasets. It is about overwriting a column of one dataset with a column of another dataset.

Comment: The only way to use a column from a DF in another DF is to perform a join. So unless, you do that, as described in the link and you create a new column on the join DF with your condition, I can't be done. Which makes this question a duplicate of the one I've linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you can't copy a column from one Dataset to the other that way.

**Problem**

Using `from.col(copyCol)` creates a reference to 'copyCol' column of 'from' dataset and when you use `withColumn`, Spark is looking in "output df" the reference from "from df" and you've got the missing attributes error.

**Solution**

If you want to copy a column from a Dataset to the other, no choice, you've got to join the datasets and select the columns you want.

```
public static void copyColumns(String copyFrom, String copyTo, String outputFile, String idCol, String[] copyCols) {
    Dataset<Row> from =  readCSV(copyFrom);
    Dataset<Row> to = readCSV(copyTo);

    for(String copyCol : copyCols) {
        to = to.join(
                from.select(idCol, copyCol),
                to.col(idCol).equalTo(from.col(idCol)),
                "left_outer"
            )
            .withColumn("NewCol",
                when(from.col(copyCol).isNotNull, from.col(copyCol))
                    .otherwise(to.col(copyCol))
            .drop(from.col(idCol))
            .drop(from.col(copyCol))
            .drop(to.col(copyCol))
            .withColumnRenamed("NewCol", copyCol);
    }

    writeCSV(to, outputFile);
}
```

[See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717708/spark-scala-copy-column-from-one-dataframe-to-another)

Comment: Your answer helped me understand about the referencing stuff. But did not completely solve my problem of conditional copying.

Comment: If you want to copy a column from one dataset to the other, you need to join the two dataset and keep the column you want. In short : your `when` condition becomes a `join` condition (here, same id) and instead of adding a column using `withColumn`, you add it through the `join` and remove useless column using`drop`

Comment: Yes. I understand this. My case is, I have to copy the values of a column from another dataset if the condition is satisfied, else I have to preserve the old data for that column.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. I've edited my answer. Basically, if the join condition couldn't be verified, the `copyCol` value should be null.

Comment: This edit has worked. I can see the expected data for the column. But, `.drop(from.col(copyCol)).drop(to.col(copyCol))` doesn't seem to work as expected. I can see two `copyCol` columns, duplicate columns I mean.

Comment: I've had a temporary column name, is it better ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197934/discussion-between-ramvignesh-and-rafael).